# How do I match the domain names with regex by omitting sub-domains?

Tags: regex

This is my regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,23}
```

which matches domains correctly

eg: `youtube.com`, `google.com` etc

while it fails to match the domain when there is a sub-domain.

eg. `www.youtube.com`, `mail.google.com`

How do I alter it to match only the domain but not the sub-domain?
I'm a beginner with regular expressions anyway I don't prefer splitting up the string and matching the part, but with regular expressions.

here's the [regexr](http://regexr.com/3b4ae)

thanks

Comment: are ip adresses allowed as well (like `127.0.0.1`)?

Comment: not really. just domains.

Comment: I see some potential problems, some countries define subdomains for their top domain like `foo.co.uk` this will not match. It is hard (and will change in time), what the difference is between a *top-level domain* and *domain name*.

Comment: @CommuSoft its okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you anchor your regex to the end of the input string it will do what you want. To do this, use a `$` at the end of the expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,23}$
```

This will then match the "goole.com" portion "mail.google.com" as well as strings without a subdomain like "google.com".

Comment: As noted in another comment, this solution won't match domains from countries that have a 2-part top-level domain like `foo.co.uk`.

Comment: Another problem is that is is unsure if this is the end of the line. For instance `google.com/search.html?q=foobar`. Because of the *dynamic nature of the Internet* and the complicated specifications of URLs it is perhaps advisable to use a library.

Comment: @CommuSoft The OP didn't mention matching whole URLs, just domains with optional sub-domain. However, if the input is going to be a URL (or anything more than just domain names) then I would agree that a library for parsing URLs would definitely be preferable to a home-grown regex.

Comment: @CommuSoft +1 for the point, I'm just concerned about the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to just fix your regex by adding some restrictions for emails:

```
(?![\d\s.]+\b)\b([0-9a-z-]{2,}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3}|[0-9a-z-]{2,}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3})(?!@)\b
```

See [updated demo](http://regexr.com/3b4ak)

I added a `i` case-insensitive option to get rid of `[A-Z]` and just use `[a-z]`.

Comment: The regex should not match with the subdomain.

Comment: @CommuSoft: It does not match the subdomains in the provided input now.